# What does "preview" an airplane on Microsoft Flight mean?

Tags: microsoft-flight

The new [Microsoft Flight](http://www.microsoft.com/games/flight/) is an awesome freemium game. The two available airplane DLC, have a free "preview". What does it mean? Are they time-limited?

Answer (score 2):

The free preview just shows what the plane looks like in the plane select menu, nothing else, because most of the DLCs are just planes

Comment: He wasn't asking what a preview *was*, but what it meant in the context of the DLC.

Comment: Yes I know that, but that's what the DLC previews are in this game

Comment: I'd recommend fleshing out your answer, then, to properly explain that.